# Manual inference using weights and biases from trained Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

### Background

I am trying to understand the details of a simple feed-forward neural network. I reproduced an example from my favourite textbook [An Introduction to Statistical Learning v2](https://www.statlearning.com/).

It is a supervised ML problem. There are 19 feature variables and the target variable is salary.

The architecture is as follows:

- input layer: 19 input nodes (1 for each feature variable)
- hidden layer: 50 nodes
- output layer: 1 node

I have trained the 1051 parameters with 150 epochs. The performance is decent.

### Problem

What I am trying to understand now is how to use the 1051 parameters for inference.

The built-in way to perform inference with Pytorch is:

```
y_pred_tensor = model(torch.tensor(X_test.values.astype(np.float32)))
```

with this I have predicted 87 salary points - where the shape of `X_test` is (87, 19).

But I am trying to understand how to do that manually with the trained parameters and without the Pytorch function.

### Solution Attempt

I am focusing on the last predicted value (848.0330) in the test set.

First I use the 19 feature values from the last row in X_test:

```
inputs = X_test.values.astype(np.float32)[-1] # (19)
```

What I am doing for each hidden node is:

- take the 19 inputs, and multiply each of them by the 19 weights.
- Sum the 19 terms together.
- Add the bias
- Pass into Relu.

code:

```
def ReLU(x):
  return x * (x > 0)

inputs = X_test.values.astype(np.float32)[-1] # (19)
hidden_weights = [p for p in model.parameters()][0].detach().numpy()  # (50, 19)
hidden_biases = [p for p in model.parameters()][1].detach().numpy()  # (50,)

inputs_hidden_layer = np.array([ReLU(i) for i in ((inputs * 
hidden_weights).sum(axis=1)+hidden_biases)])
```

What I am doing for the output node is:

- multiply the 50 numbers (calculated for each node from the above bullets) by the 50 output weights, sum them together, add the bias term.

code:

```
output_weights = [p for p in model.parameters()][2].detach().numpy()  # (50,)
output_bias = [p for p in model.parameters()][3].detach().numpy()[0]  # (1,)
final_result = (output_weights * inputs_hidden_layer)[0].sum() + output_bias
```

The `final_result` is 660 and not the 848 obtained when using the build-in function.

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/oliverangelil/ipynb/blob/master/deep-learning/ISLR2_Ch10_9_1.ipynb).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the line:

```
model.eval()
```

before making inference.

This prevents dropout being applied at inference.

More information can be found at [this](https://medium.com/artificialis/dropout-regularization-using-pytorch-in-python-7765337cb158) medium blog post.